# Left navigation shows "error"

Tags: navigation, sorting

After changes in Quick Launch sorting properties I made them to sort automatically based on title.

After that left Quick Launch "Error".

I am unable to determine the cause. Can anyone help suggest what/witch parts that are involved in finding the cause for errors related to working with Navigation in SharePoint?

Comment: What specific changes you made and what error do you get ? Kindly add more details to your question like an error screenshot or uls log message etc,. to help us understand the problem better.

Comment: @arko-d: Sorry about that. It was due to a list rename.I deleted that list and created new one.